# C - How do I print out characters between double quotes in a string array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, double-quotes

Suppose I have a character array as shown below:

```
char a[20] = "abc\"defg\"hij";
```

How do I get it print `defg`  ?

I thought of iterating through the array. When I find the first double quote, I begin printing the characters until another double quote is seen. It then breaks out of the loop. Is there a 'cleaner' way to achieve this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: You can use Regular Expression (in `regex.h`), and you'll have two problems.

Comment: What should be the output if there's only one double quote in the string?  If there are three, four, …?  If you only need to print characters after the first double quote up to the next double quote or end of string, then what you outline is OK.  If you must not print anything if there isn't a second double quote, you have to check ahead before printing anything. If you have to handle multiple sets of double quotes, you can't stop so quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strchr()`, like this

```
const char *head = strchr(a, '"');
if (head != NULL) {
    const char *tail = strchr(head + 1, '"');
    if (tail == NULL)
        tail = strchr(head + 1, '\0');
    fwrite(head + 1, 1, tail - head - 1, stdout);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

But this works for very simple cases, you did not specify whether you needed a general solution or just a solution for this very case.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think that your proposition is the cleanest. You could of course use `strsep()`, `strchr()` or `regex.h` but for your needs I think your solution is the cleanest. Everything else will result in a mess, there is no "one-liner" for this.

If you want to clean up, you can put your idea in another function that will return the string between the `""`, that will at least a bit clean up your main function.

Comment: You are right in the sense that any other solution will ultimately do almost exactly what the OP described. But also, most algorithms from the standard library would search more efficiently in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strtok` method in `string.h`, which breaks the given string in tokens, given a delimiter.

In your example, you would use it like this:

```
/* set the `"` delimiter for the string `a` */
char *token;
token = strtok(a,"\"");

/* by printing out token now, you'd have `abc` as output */
/* but we want the second token */
token = strtok(NULL,"\"");

/* while using strtok any other time, you have to put NULL instead of the string you want to tokenize, as it maintains an internal buffer - extremely thread unsafe! */

printf("%s\n",token);
/* the output will be: defg */
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I change a to :    `char a[20] = "\"defg\"";`

Comment: Don't use `strtok` for this, it modifies the source string.

Comment: then you might try using `strstr` twice:
`char *start= strstr(a,"\"");` `char *end = strstr(start,"\"");` `int len = strlen(start) - strlen(end);` `char *word;` `snprintf("%s",len,start);` and finally `printf("%s\n",word);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way, that does not modify the source string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[20] = "abc\"defg\"hij";  
    int n1 = strcspn(a, "\"");
    int n2 = (a[n1] == '\"') ? strcspn(a + n1 + 1, "\"") : 0;
    printf("%.*s\n", n2, a + n1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `size_t strcspn()`.